# How to display int from web page (webscraping) in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, html-agility-pack

I need somebody who tell me how to use Html Agility Pack in Windows Forms.
I have
`private void btnOnet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        doc = web.Load("https://pogoda.onet.pl/");
        var temperatura = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class, 'temperature')]/div[contains(@class, 'temp')]");
        onet.Text = temperatura.InnerHtml;
    }    `
```

I don't know how to display result in textBox aftek click Button.
Should I create another method or do all in  private void btnOnet_Click

Comment: `web.Load()` will quite probably load the HTML source before it's rendered. So, also most probably, the element you're looking for has not been created yet, so `temperatura` is going to be null (something you can test yourself, debugging your code) -- Not an `int`, it would be a string, since it comes from a text source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrape data from div in Windows.Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71967403/scrape-data-from-div-in-windows-form)