# How to scrap data from web in Windows Forms use html agility pack? How to get correct Xpath?

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack

I don't know what is wrong with this code. I can't see result in textBox.
Somebody can check if the XPath is correct? And where is mistake??

namespace Pogoda
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
public Form2()
{
InitializeComponent();
}
public static bool TryGetTemperature(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc, out int temperature)
{
temperature = 0;

```
        var temp = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(
            "//div(@class, 'temperature')]/div[contains(@class, 'temp')]");
        return temp != null ?
            int.TryParse(temp.InnerText.TrimEnd('°'), out temperature) :
            false;
    }
  
    private void btnOnet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        doc = web.Load("https://pogoda.onet.pl");
        if (TryGetTemperature(doc, out int temperature))
        {
            onet.Text = temperature.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }


   
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrape data from div in Windows.Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71967403/scrape-data-from-div-in-windows-form)